# Wait on thread for UI activity

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have read a lot on threading but can't figure out a way to make this one work right. So it should really be obvious how to do this as it usually is with me (always missing the obvious) :p

Here's my problem (BTW, am working with `WPF` in `C#`):

I have a long running process i'm running on a separate thread while the UI stays responsinve and showing evolution. However, mid-process, i need to ask the user to confirm a value before proceeding. That's what i can't figure out, cause the window to confirm the value must be run in the UI thread and still return the value to the work thread so it can continue it's work.

So...

```
Long running process beeing run in work thread
Work thread waits for UI Thread
    UI thread shows the confirmation window
    User confirms/fixes value and closes the confirmation window
    UI thread sends result from confirmation window to work thread
work thread gets values from UI Thread (value was changed by user? to what?)
work thread continues long running process
Work thread gets values from confirmation window
```

I've already the work thread working well using ThreadPool - although am open to using threading in different ways (NET 4.5). Problem i am having is that if i send the confirmation window part to dispatcher my work thread won't wait for the results from the confirmation window. If i don't put in the dispatcher i get an exception about not beeing in an STA thread when the window constructor is called.

Any ideas welcome

Comment: Could you have two functions? One that runs pre-user input, and one that runs post-user input?

Comment: Wouldn't the UI get stuck while i wait for pre-user input part to finish?

Comment: No, you thread it (as you do now) The user input appears when the thread completes (using a callback or event) and then the second thread/function kicks off.

Comment: Interesting idea (obvious really) - i will test but sounds solid - put it as answer and if works i'll give it to you

Comment: Done! Hopefully it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to block the worker thread waiting on UI (not saying you *couldn't* do it, but it would be messy).

A much simpler solution would be to split up your process into *two* threads; one that runs pre-user input, and one that runs after. You would prompt the user upon the first thread's completion (via a callback or event).

Something like (pseudo-code)

```
InitialThreadObject.Completed += () =>
  {
      PromptForUI();
      SecondThreadObject.Start();
  } 
InitialThreadObject.Start();
```

Obviously you would choose the completion notification mechanism based on your current code.